# ffi_prep_cif() returned an FFI_BAD_TYPEDEF error

Tags: objective-c, node.js, macos, avfoundation, nodobjc

I'm trying to port the following code from Objective-C to Node.js:

```
[[self.output connectionWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo] setVideoMinFrameDuration: CMTimeMake(1, 30)];
```

I'm writing the following:

```
this.output('connectionWithMediaType', macOS.AVMediaTypeVideo)('setVideoMinFrameDuration', macOS.CMTimeMake(1, 30));
```

Where `macOS` is a `NodObjC` instance.

When I run it, I get the following:

```
App threw an error during load
Error: ffi_prep_cif() returned an FFI_BAD_TYPEDEF error
at CIF (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/node_modules/ffi/lib/cif.js:60:19)
at Object.ForeignFunction (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/node_modules/ffi/lib/foreign_function.js:33:13)
at Object.createUnwrapperFunction (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/node_modules/nodobjc/lib/core.js:299:22)
at ID.module.exports.Class.msgSend (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/node_modules/nodobjc/lib/class.js:186:53)
at rtn (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/node_modules/nodobjc/lib/core.js:375:47)
at new Aperture (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/lib/main.js:40:65)
at Object.module.exports [as main] (/Users/matheus/dev/node/aperture/lib/main.js:95:9)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/matheus/dev/node/focus/index.js:2:41)
at Module._compile (module.js:541:32)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:550:10)
```

Everything else in the app is working – that is, I ported every other line of code and it's working.

Thanks!

Comment: 1) Try dividing the line of code into two statements to see exactly where it is bailing out.  2) setVideoMinFrameDuration: appears to have been deprecated.  Not knowing better, I wonder if that implies that it may no longer be bridged?

Comment: It's deprecated on iOS but not on macOS :) I already divided it in two statements; Posted here in this way to make it shorter. The call to `setVideoMin/MaxFrameDuration` is the one that is failing :/ Thanks for the help!

Comment: Hrm; OK.   Anyway to introspect the types required? Have you tried breaking out the CMTimeMake() and introspecting the type that is returned?

Comment: It returns a `CMTime`. I can call `CMTimeSHow` with the returned value and it prints correctly (that is, equal to what I get on pure Obj-C)

Comment: Can you introspect the type of the method as it appears in JS?  I suspect that the wrapper is missing the type information for that argument and, thus, that would cause the FFI_BAD_TYPEDEF error.  Specifically, where does foreign_function.js grab the bridging metadata?

Comment: OK -- I have a better guess as to where this is going off the rails.  I suspect that nodobjc doesn't have any metadata on the CMTime() type when it is trying to call the set method.  On OS X, there exists bridge support files in the frameworks that nodobjc uses to deduce method parameter types.  If that doesn't exist or is not being used on iOS, then you'll get a FFI_BAD_TYPEDEF when nodobjc passes NULL to one of the ffi* functions.

Comment: If you wanted to debug this, modify createUnwrapperFunction() in nodobjc to log the type that is passed in.  If it really is using bridge support compatible types, then you need to figure out how to inject `{_CMTime=qiIq}` for the type of the CMTime argument.

Comment: Yeah-- the functional interfaces are bridged differently than the ObjC interfaces, it seems, and, thus, making the call via the functional interface is more likely to work because there is less layers of metadata abstraction.